# Install Bitnami Redmine stack on an existing Mysql database

Tags: mysql, redmine, bitnami

I'm using Ubuntu server. I'm already using a Mysql server and I want to add Redmine to it. The problem is that I'm not sure when Mysql server is installed by "Bitnami Redmine stack" again, if my old database will still be usable or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you already had a MySQL database running in port 3306 when you installed the BitNami Redmine stack you should have prompted for entering a new port for the MySQL server bundled in the stack. Your old database should be still usable, but your BitNami installation will use its own MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you using same port need to stop it and start the mysql of bitnami redmin using **ctrlscript** .

I have already add the installation document for bitnami redmine and issues related with that while installing in below mentioned link.

[Issues related to starting mysql while installing redmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791931/redmine3-3-0-1-bundle-install-server-500-error/44824252#44824252)