# Redmine3.3.0-1 Bundle install server 500 Error

Tags: redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins, bundle-install

I installed BITNAMI RedMine 3.3.0-1. After installing version Plugins, 500 error appears on the server.

I could not solve this. 
I did everything until bundle install, but I get an error.

[enter image description here][1]

```
Web application could not be started
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem.  Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install
If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the daemon user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Error ID
a0d9ba99
Application root
/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/bin/ruby
User and groups
uid=2(daemon) gid=2(daemon) groups=2(daemon),1(bin),4(adm),7(lp) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Environment variables
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR = /tmp/orbit-ialab
LDAPCONF = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib 
HOSTNAME = ialab
IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP = yes
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = 27488
SSL_CERT_FILE = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/openssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt
GEM_HOME = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0
SHELL = /sbin/nologin
TERM = xterm
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID = 
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE = e33f5a39112e173914eed31100000010-1495711078.860427-1274300290
HISTSIZE = 1000
CURL_CA_BUNDLE = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/openssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt
PERL5LIB = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/lib/site_perl/5.16.3:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib/5.16.3:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib/site_perl/5.16.3:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.5/config:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
GTK_RC_FILES = /etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/ialab/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
GS_LIB = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/share/ghostscript/fonts
WINDOWID = 52472147
LC_NUMERIC = C
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXekPYAD
QTDIR = /usr/lib64/qt-3.3
QTINC = /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
GIT_SSL_CAINFO = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/openssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt
OPENSSL_ENGINES = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib/engines
IMSETTINGS_MODULE = none
USER = daemon
MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.5/modules-Q16/coders
LS_COLORS = rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/subversion/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/sqlite/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/mysql/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apache2/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/subversion/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/sqlite/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/mysql/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apache2/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/lib/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/sqlite/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/subversion/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/postgresql/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/mysql/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apache2/lib:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib:
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/keyring-xETGIW/socket.ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET = /tmp/keyring-xETGIW/socket
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT = /redmine
IN_PASSENGER = 1
SESSION_MANAGER = local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2901,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2901
USERNAME = ialab
CXXFLAGS = -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include 
RACK_ENV = production
SCRIPT_URI = http://127.0.0.1:3000/redmine
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
DESKTOP_SESSION = gnome
MAIL = /var/spool/mail/ialab
PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/perl/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/sqlite/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/subversion/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/postgresql/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/php/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/mysql/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apache2/bin:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ialab/bin
WSGI_ENV = production
SCRIPT_URL = /redmine
QT_IM_MODULE = xim
    = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/manager-linux-x64.run
PWD = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apps/redmine/htdocs
XMODIFIERS = @im=none
PHP_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/php/bin/php
GDM_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT = us
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID = 2891
GDM_LANG = en_US.UTF-8
SASL_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib/sasl2
NODE_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/node_lib
NODE_ENV = production
GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/share/git-core/templates
GDMSESSION = gnome
MAGICK_HOME = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common
RUBY_HOME = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby
HISTCONTROL = ignoredups
SSH_ASKPASS = /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
SASL_CONF_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/etc
SHLVL = 7
HOME = /sbin
TERMINFO = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/share/terminfo
RAILS_ENV = production
OPENSSL_CONF = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/openssl/openssl.cnf
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = this-is-deprecated
CFLAGS = -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include 
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h SVN/1.8.16 PHP/5.6.23 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.6
LOGNAME = daemon
CVS_RSH = ssh
QTLIB = /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-tfHoZxB28Y,guid=fa282f9e81d15bbf69932f460000004a
GEM_PATH = 
LESSOPEN = ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
PKG_CONFIG_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib/pkgconfig
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
GITPERLLIB = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/lib/site_perl/5.16.3
DISABLE_BANNER = YES
WINDOWPATH = 1
DISPLAY = :0.0
RUBYLIB = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/:/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib
BUNDLE_CONFIG = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/.bundler/config
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES = 1
GIT_EXEC_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/git/libexec/git-core/
XAUTHORITY = /root/.xauthFoxH5y
COLORTERM = gnome-terminal
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
Ulimits
Unknown
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
Uptime            : 33d 22h 4m 18s
Load averages     : 0.99%, 0.80%, 0.82%
Fork rate         : unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :    4
Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 2           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 3           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 4           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
I/O pressure      :   0%
  CPU 1           :   0%
  CPU 2           :   0%
  CPU 3           :   0%
  CPU 4           :   0%
Interference from other VMs:   0%
  CPU 1                    :   0%
  CPU 2                    :   0%
  CPU 3                    :   0%
  CPU 4                    :   0%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :   7748 MB
RAM used          :   2526 MB (33%)
RAM free          :   5221 MB
Swap total        :   7887 MB
Swap used         :     17 MB (0%)
Swap free         :   7870 MB
Swap in           : unknown
Swap out          : unknown

General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 2.1.9
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.2.5
RubyGems paths = ["/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0"]
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 2
MINOR = 1
TEENY = 0
PATCHLEVEL = 490
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-2.1.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorarchhdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorhdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/ruby-2.1.0
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH = 
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--prefix=/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby' '--with-openssl-dir=/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common' '--enable-pthread' '--disable-install-doc' '--with-readline-dir=/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common' 'CC=gcc' 'CFLAGS=-fPIC -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -fPIC -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -fPIC -m64 -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick -O3' 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include/sasl -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include'
vendorarchdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
vendordir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitearchdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
sitedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby
rubyarchdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
rubylibdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0
ruby_version = 2.1.0
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearchincludedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/x86_64-linux
archincludedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include/x86_64-linux
sitearchlibdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/x86_64-linux
archlibdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/x86_64-linux
libdirname = libdir
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby
RUBY_LIB_VERSION = 
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE = 3  /* full */
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/ri
rubysitearchprefix = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchprefix = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
MAKEFILES = Makefile GNUmakefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = 
ENABLE_SHARED = no
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lgmp 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib 
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBY = libruby-static.a
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.1.0
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
EXTLDFLAGS = 
strict_warnflags = -std=iso9899:1999
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags = -ggdb3
optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
cxxflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags = 
NULLCMD = :
DLNOBJ = dln.o
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
DTRACE_GLOMMED_OBJ = 
DTRACE_OBJ = 
DTRACE_EXT = dmyh
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
RUNRUBY_COMMAND = $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext $(RUNRUBYOPT)
PREP = miniruby
BTESTRUBY = $(MINIRUBY)
CROSS_COMPILING = no
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
rubylibprefix = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby
setup = Setup
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK = 
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO = 
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = -m64
DLDFLAGS = 
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
PYTHON = /bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/python/bin/python
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
DTRACE = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
CC_VERSION = gcc -v
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
LD = ld
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CXX = g++
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS = -DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include/sasl -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include  
LDFLAGS = -L. -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/lib -L/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/lib -L/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/lib -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS = -fPIC -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -fPIC -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -I/opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/common/include -fPIC -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick -I/bitnami/rubystack-linux-x64/output/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick -O3
CC = gcc
NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
target_os = linux
target_vendor = pc
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = pc
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-2.1.0
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = pc
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2016-03-30
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.1.9
target_alias = 
host_alias = 
build_alias = 
LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/man
localedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/locale
libdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib
psdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/info
docdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/include
localstatedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/var
sharedstatedir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/com
sysconfdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/etc
datadir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share
datarootdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/share
libexecdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/libexec
sbindir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/sbin
bindir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/bin
exec_prefix = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/sh
archdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
topdir = /opt/redmine-3.3.0-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
Activated Ruby gems
bundler => 1.10.4
io-console => 0.4.3
psych => 2.0.5
```

Comment: Right under `bundle install` it asks you if you're in the right environment. Are you? Look up "RAILS_ENV" if you're not familiar with what this means, it's an environment variable that determines the environment Rails is in.

Comment: I'm sorry I did bundle install, but it seems to be a bad install.
I can not fix the error.

Comment: Did you do it in the right environment?

Comment: Thank you.
I installed it with version 2.2 and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here,

in case you are installing a new plugin, you need to follow the next steps:

- Check that the plugin is compatible with your Redmine version.
- Load the Bitnami environment

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/bnconsole/

- If the plugin requires a migration, run the following commands to upgrade your database. It is advisable to back up the database before running these commands.

`cd installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite
ruby bin/rake redmine:plugins RAILS_ENV=production`

- Restart Redmine
- After copying the plugin into the installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins directory, run these commands:

`cd installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite --no-deployment
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite --deployment
ruby bin/rake redmine:plugins RAILS_ENV=production`

- Restart Redmine

I hope it helps.
Jota

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related with your gem files. PLease check your gemfile's versions.

View the below link to get the installation steps for bitnami-Redmine,

[Steps to install bitnami redmine](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2017/06/17/bitnami-redmine-installation/)